# Import only selected features from different layers into print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I want to make a printable map in the print composer that only contains the selected polygons from different layers. Is that possible and if so how do I do it? The marked features on the picture below consists of three different layers, and i want to avoid the other polygons that are not marked. I am using QGIS 2.8.2 [image]

Comment: your qgis version is pretty old. the last LTR is 2.18

Answer (score 3):

The solution depends on how the selected polygons are defined in the attribute table.

If there is any unique value or text that can isolate the selected polygons from the other polygons in the same layer, then you can use `Query Builder` from `Layer properties -> General -> Query Builder` and write an expression that can make the selected polygon visible and hide other polygons based on how they are defined in the attribute table.

If you cannot select the feature using an expression in Query Builder, then the only way, as far as I know, is to save the selected polygon into a new shapefile and load them again to create a layout for them.

Comment: on the second way you loose the style and you should create 3 diferents shapefile (because of the model)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a **rule-based symbology** using the **isselected()** function.

```
isselected(@layer_name)
```

This function is provided by Nathan Woodrow's **Expression Plus** Plugin.